# Is there a <NotIn> LINQ method?

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a `NotIn` LINQ method ?

```
// A: 1,2,3,4,5
// B: 4,5,6,7,8

C = A.NotIn(B);

// C: 1,2,3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`IEnumerable<T>.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx)

```
var a = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
var b = new int[] {4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
var c = a.Except(b);
foreach(var x in c)
    Console.WriteLine(x);
```

output:

```
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is. It's called `Except`.

So in your case, `C = A.Except(B);`

Answer (score 2):

That will be [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx) (assuming `A` and `B` are enumerable):

```
var C = A.Except(B);
```